# OpenSSL's command for Partial Chain in Python

Tags: python, openssl, x509certificate, pycrypto, pyopenssl

I'm trying to use `OpenSSL` module in Python for certificate validation.

I have window's `openssl` command as:

`openssl verify -partial_chain -CAfile Intermediate.pem UserCert.pem`

Will you please suggest me equivalent of this in Python?

Requirement: This needs to be done by `OpenSSL` or any Python3 module. Use of `os.system` will solve the problem but this won't satisfy the requirement.

Comment: If you have WSL try `import os` newline `os.system('cmd /c "bash -c openssl verify -partial_chain -CAfile Intermediate.pem UserCert.pem"')` This will create a cmd instance that accesses your WSL to execute the `OpenSSL` bash command in a cmd window then close it. To keep it open use `/k` instead of `/c`. To see if this works, first open a command prompt and run the command `bash -c openssl verify -partial_chain -CAfile Intermediate.pem UserCert.pem` and see if it returns what you want then try running it from python.

Comment: Then my comment is not what you are looking for. Can you put more detail in your question detailing your constraints and other limitations then? Accessing WSL with `os.system` will allow you to use `OpenSSL`

Comment: Can you call cmd? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900884/running-openssl-system-call

Comment: I want this to do be done completely in Python. Nothing from cmd or os. I need proper function to do this.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602843/how-to-import-openssl-in-python/30602906) answer your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216447/discussion-between-neko-musume-and-bogota).

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same issue, and ended up solving it using pure pyopenssl:

```py
import OpenSSL
import ssl

host = 'my.endpoint.com'
port = 443

partial_chain = ... # The partial chain to verify against, as a list of strings

urlcert = ssl.get_server_certificate((host, port))

certificate = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, urlcert)

store = OpenSSL.crypto.X509Store()

# populate store
for i in partial_chain:  
  store.add_cert(OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, i))

# Set partial chain validation
store.set_flags(OpenSSL.crypto.X509StoreFlags.PARTIAL_CHAIN) 

store_ctx = OpenSSL.crypto.X509StoreContext(store, certificate)

try:
    store_ctx.verify_certificate()
    return True
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
    return False
```